# Are we just a simulation

Tags: ontology

Do we live in a simulation?  Is the world just a hologram?  I assume that this is the same question, but see no references to holograms.  Am I correct that this is the same question?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Please visit our [Help Center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help) to see what questions we answer and how to ask. [Holography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holographic_principle) and the [simulation hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulation_hypothesis) have nothing to do with each other. Questions about simulation were already asked here multiple times and have answers.

Comment: I don't think the question is a pure duplicate. The questioner is asking more than merely whether the simulation hypothesis is outside science.

Comment: @GeoffreyThomas The criterion for duplicate is not a match on the question but whether available answers answer it. This question is so vague that it is answered there to the extent that it can be answered at all, and that thread is just one of (too) many on simulation. Duplicate was an alternative to "unclear what you are asking" and "too broad". We should probably consider adding "does not show enough research effort" as another reason, like other SE.

Comment: @Conifold. Thanks for the explanation : scienti cedo .

Comment: I am new here and will be more careful....thanks all  ..   John

Answer (score 1):

A simulation represents (in any of a variety of ways) another thing. I can simulate another person's emotions, beliefs, desires, &c. I can do this e.g. by imagining how I would think or feel in their situation as I understand it. A hologram is a representation but is limited to what can be represented by light waves. Here is President Trump and here, safely in a case, is a three-dimensional image of President Trump that looks just like him.

If we lived (wholly) in a simulation where would we get the idea of a simulation? So my answer, duly provisional, is 'no'. If you want to think further about simulation and the philosophical questions and issues it raises, I agree with Conifold that you should drop the idea of a hologram from your inquiry. It is unnecessary and irrelevant. That's not meant to be harsh statement, just a guiding judgement.

Comment: @John. You have an answer to your question.